# Resize Photoshop windows that extend offscreen?

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop

After using Photoshop with an external display and having the "Layers" and other windows extended the full height of the display, when I unplug the external display, the bottom of those windows go offscreen, so I can't see the bottom of them, and can't get at the resize control in the bottom right of the window.  How can I resize them?

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to Window->Workspace->Reset Essentials worked.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer didn't really do it for me as the bottom of the Photoshop window was the problem and was still out of reach after reset essentials. What finally worked was moving the whole workspace down so I could get at the top edge with the cursor and get a vertical resize cursor to display so that I could shrink the workspace from the top (never knew I could do that!). After making it shorter, I then dragged the Photoshop window back up to the top of the computer screen and the lower right corner was again available.